# Jquery accordions not working in IE 9?

Tags: jquery, accordion

Why doesn't this work in IE 9? 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BPmHW/)
it refuses to open on click, it works fine on all browsers except IE9 > I just can't seem to figure out why!
any help is much appriciated.

```
/* Accordions */
$(".acc_item").click(function(){

    $(this).siblings().children(".accordion_content").not($(this).find(".accordion_content")).slideUp(600,'easeInOutExpo');
    $(this).siblings().children(".accordion").not($(this).find(".accordion")).removeClass("active_acc");

    $(this).find(".accordion").next(".accordion_content").slideToggle(600,'easeInOutExpo');

    if($(this).find(".accordion").hasClass('active_acc')){
        $(this).find(".accordion").removeClass("active_acc");
    }else{
        $(this).find(".accordion").addClass("active_acc");
    }
});

// Open First item if accordion whenever set so
setTimeout(function(){$(".acc_is_open").delay(1500).click();},600); 
/* Accordions::END */
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BPmHW/3/)

```
$(".acc_item").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings().children(".accordion_content").slideUp(600, 'easeInOutExpo');
    $(this).siblings().children(".accordion").removeClass("active_acc");

    $(this).find(".accordion_content").slideToggle(600, 'easeInOutExpo');

    if ($(this).find(".accordion").hasClass('active_acc')) {
        $(this).find(".accordion").removeClass("active_acc");
    } else {
        $(this).find(".accordion").addClass("active_acc");
    }
});

setTimeout(function () {
    $(".acc_is_open").delay(1500).click();
}, 600);
```

Comment: `.not($(this).find("selector"))`  could be a reason.. it is unwanted as the element itself will never be selected when we call `siblings()`.. `siblings()` takes only neighbours of same level..

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).find(".accordion_content").slideToggle(600,'easeInOutExpo');
```

Also notice that I have included the easing plugin.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/BPmHW/2/)